# check if button clicked or not in pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

Hello guys I want to check if the button clicked or not

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        loadUi("app.ui", self)
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('discord.png'))
        self.setWindowFlag(Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint, False)
        self.setWindowFlag(Qt.WindowMaximizeButtonHint, False)
        self.setFixedSize(self.size())
        self.regis = self.findChild(QPushButton, "pushButton")
        self.regis.clicked.connect(self.connectt)
        self.cl = self.findChild(QPushButton, "pushButton_2")     
        self.show()
        QApplication.processEvents()
        
    def connectt(self): 
            ID = self.findChild(QLineEdit, "lineEdit")
            RP = Presence(ID.text())
            RP.connect()
            print("connected")
            self.statusBar.showMessage('connected') 
            if self.cl.clicked():
               print("disconnected")
                               
app = QApplication(sys.argv)

UIWindow = MainWindow()
app.exec_()
```

I tried to use self.cl.clicked() but it didn't work!

but I got this error :

```
    if self.cl.clicked():
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: native Qt signal is not callable
```

can anyone help me, please

Answer (score 1):

You don't need your "if self.cl.clicked():

Assuming "regis" is your button, this line :

```
self.regis.clicked.connect(self.connectt)
```

makes it that as soon as you click your "regis" button, the whole "connectt" function will execute.

And if "cl" is another button, your code makes no sense to me, because what your doing is you verify if your "cl" button is clicked when you click your "regis" button (basically clicking two buttons at the same time, which feels strange in my opinion). Maybe you should think about another way to do what you're trying to do.

Let me know if this answered your question.

Edit:
You can use the codeblock like:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        loadUi("app.ui", self)
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('discord.png'))
        self.setWindowFlag(Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint, False)
        self.setWindowFlag(Qt.WindowMaximizeButtonHint, False)
        self.setFixedSize(self.size())
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.pushButtonOperations)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.pushButton_2Operations)

        self.cl = self.findChild(QPushButton, "pushButton_2")     
        self.show()
        QApplication.processEvents()
        
    def pushButtonOperations(self): 
        ID = self.findChild(QLineEdit, "lineEdit")
        RP = Presence(ID.text())
        RP.connect()
        print("connected")
        self.statusBar.showMessage('connected')
    def pushButton_2Operations(self):
        print("disconnected")                               
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
UIWindow = MainWindow()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: It might make sense if the `cl` button was [checkable](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#checkable-prop). Then the OP could do `if self.cl.isChecked():`.